# Pull last record from Treatments but not eliminate all events

Tags: sql

I have this data and I need to select the max value from each time period.  I know how to select the Max event but that will eliminate data I need.

```
Patient Treatment           ActivityDate      Keep

15308   Initial Simulation  3/6/14 5:08 PM  

15308   Initial Simulation  3/7/14 2:37 PM      *

15308   Re-Simulation       3/14/14 4:44 PM 

15308   Re-Simulation       3/17/14 11:56 AM    *

15308   Re-Simulation       4/17/14 9:54 AM 

15308   Initial Simulation  4/17/14 9:54 AM     *

15309   Initial Simulation  2/20/14 4:33 PM 

15309   Initial Simulation  2/21/14 2:38 PM     *

15309   Re-Simulation       3/26/14 9:29 AM     *
```

I want to Keep the Max Treatment from each patient for each time period.  I'm thinking that maybe I could have a 5 day range and pull the max from that?  Any ideas are very welcome.

I'm using SQL 2008

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Why is `15308   Re-Simulation       3/17/14 11:56 AM`    * kept vs `15308   Re-Simulation       4/17/14 9:54 AM `  The expected results are clear with the * on keep (I think) but I can't see a pattern which would select those values.

Comment: Good question.  They have the same date.  That happens some times.

Comment: But that's not the same date.  one is 3/17, the other is 4/17 a month apart assuming m/d/y format.

Comment: "I want to Keep the Max Treatment from each patient for each time period." How do you define Time Period here?

Comment: and what determines a max of treatment? the activity date?  if so I go back to why is 1308 Re-Simulation not keeping 4/17/14 9:54AM instead of 3/17/14 @ 11:56AM... at which point the answer I provided works.  So I'm at a loss...

Comment: I agree with XQbert...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Patient, Treatment, Max(ActivityDate)
From Table
Group by Patient, Treatment
```

This seems pretty straight forward so I must be missing something.

Comment: I want to have the max event of each time period.  If I do Max(ActivityDate) it will eliminate other activities.

Comment: Ex.  
Initial Simulation 2/20/14 4:33 PM
Initial Simulation 2/21/14 2:38 PM
Initial Simulation 3/26/14 9:29 AM

I want the 2/21 2:38 and the 3/26 events

Comment: Ok so what is a max event?  and how are time periods determined?

Comment: Edit origional Post.  It will help others

Comment: Thanks xQ!  How do you make columns?

Comment: I want the max event for each time period.  2 events could come 5 days before or after each other.

Comment: If I pull max of these, I will only have 3/26

2/20/14 4:33 PM

2/21/14 2:38 PM

3/26/14 9:29 AM

I want 2/21 and 3/26 because they are the max of each time period.

Comment: Gotta admit I'm at a loss.  I don't understand the problem well enough to help.

Comment: i think  you are missing more info here.. because what you are expecting here can not happen with given info. you must be missing column for us to see.

Comment: That's what I thought AJ.  I wish my data had a field to group by but it is missing.